# Check the version of an assembly without loading it

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method which checks the version of an assembly and if it's out of date overrides it.  To detect the version I'm using the following code:

```
version = Type.GetType(typeName).Assembly.GetName().Version;
```

However, if I deem that this version is out of date when I try and override it I get the following error

> *The process cannot access the file... because it is being used by another process.*

It seems to me that the act of reflecting the assembly is causing it to load into the program and so it can't be overridden.

How can I either

1. Check the version without loading the assembly
2. Unload the assembly before overriding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just [redirect assembly versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx).

Comment: +1 for [XY-answering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

Load the copy of your assembly in the following way.

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("YourAssembly.dll"));
```

You can now override the assembly that's on your disk.

Comment: How can you read a file when it is been used by(without `FileSharing`) another process?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel how is that related?

Comment: @sehe If am not wrong try this snippet`            FileStream fs = new FileStream("YourAssembly.dll", FileMode.Open);
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("YourAssembly.dll"));` this will throw `IOException`

Comment: The previous process should not block it for reading only. Typically when running an executable file, other processes cannot write to it, but still read from, specifing those locking flags should work. Not sure about the shortcut method `ReadAllBytes` though.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel - The ReadAllBytes(string) method loads the copy of the assembly into your memory. You can then read this loaded assembly, and get the desired info from the loaded assembly. In this case, the user wants the assembly version. While at the same time, you can delete or update the assembly that's still on your disk. In other words, the file is not being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Mono.Cecil

- http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil

which is a superior (well, pre-Roslyn) CIL assembly reader/writer.